# How do you drive a light colour based on a colorRamp inside Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, custom-attributes

Im Trying to automate the process of retroilluminating the face of a robot by copying the color of the emotion displayed(blueish for neutral red for anger atm) on a light thats pointing the face of the robot.

This is the way im taking the RGB values out of my colorRamp
[image]

1- I have a value drived by a shape key that picks the color of the light depending on the emotion.
2- the colorRamps picks the color

3- im taking each float value and storing them as attributes

the problem comes whem im trying to drive the color of an area light based on this float values i stored/captured.

[image]

Is there any way to drive them using the values one can capture from Geometry nodes?

Comment: Attribut name is a string of course, not a value. Are you using Cycles or Eevee?

Comment: eevee, is there any way to have control over each color chanel, linked to the colorramp?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, Geometry Nodes is unnecessary element in this setup. Create a new value in controller object:

[image]

Then I suppose you can use this value for driver.

Then you can arrange driver curves to get the right colors like this (you can add more points (turn snapping off) to get more colors):

[image]

Comment: the thing is i need to drive it with specific values coming our of the shader editor or Geometry nodes, likely the ones that create and write info on attributes i can later use